# Unable to retrieve the session collection properties

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, rds, remoteapp

Server 2012 R2 RDS.  This server has been running well and I have a handful of remote applications published.  All applications work fine.  Now when I attempt to edit a published application, or publish a new application, I get the error: Unable to retrieve the session collection properties.  Subsequently, I am unable to publish any new remote applications.  I've gone through the license troubleshooter (all good).  This Server is hosting all deployment roles for RDS.  I have deployed other servers in the same fashion with no trouble.  This problem just suddenly arose about a month ago.  Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The user (who is apparently no longer with us) solved his own problem thus:

> I have found the fix (for me at least).  In Server Manger > Remote Desktop Services > Collections > QuickSessionCollection > Properties of the collection - Click Tasks - Edit Properties. Add "Domain Admins" to user group. Save. Now you once again able to edit RemoteApp Programs and Publish new.
>
> I do not know if it was a Domain Admins piece, or just editing that portion of the properties that effected it.  Either way, I am in good shape now