# can't add RDSH to existing collections: Unable to retrieve the session collection properties

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, remote-desktop-services, remoteapp

For the last couple of days we are unable to add a session host to our collection, we tried with server manager and powershell, we added domains to the collection group, we moved the server to a OU that has no GPO's, nothing works. the error message is Unable to retrieve the session collection properties.

Any help would be appreciated. thanks

Comment: This worked for me https://serverfault.com/questions/653322/unable-to-retrieve-the-session-collection-properties/887485#887485

Answer (score -1):

I recently have the same issue.

Someone deleted the group that gives permission to the old collection for this servers from AD before getting servers off from collection. And then when trying to add this servers to another collection give the error that you have.

I used a different collection (maybe can be new) with the Domain Admins. as permission group for the collection. Join the servers to this collection, servers should be added successfully, then unjoin servers from this collection and join it to the original target collection.

Maybe some security entry is defined elsewhere in the configuration and the deleted group cause the issue. Just speculation.

Hope to help